# How to write this simple task of unimodular prime search in mathematica?

Tags: number-theory, procedural-programming, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations, big-numbers

For testing a particular algorithm I found mathematica is the best way as it has all the tools I need. I am stuck in a number theory part and since I am not an expert in mathematica I do not know how to write a code that seemingly involves loops. I want to pick random integers $a,b$ in interval $[T,2T]$ at $T>0$ and obtain $u,v\in\mathbb Z$ such that

1. $au-bv=1$ (Euclidean algorithm)
2. $au+bv$ is a prime
3. $GCD(ab,uv)=1$
4. $0<u,v<4T$

holds.

Is there simple enough code to do this?

It would help me to have 5. $a,b,u,v$ are all prime integers.

Comment: You realize there will very likely be an infinite number of such $u,v$ pairs? Or is just one instance enough? I suggest using the `FindInstance[]` function without any loops.

Comment: There are so many conditions. If I know correct a and b find instance will work. Or else it is quadratic diophantine.

Comment: I think this is misworded. In general such `u,v` need not exist. Are you wanting code that will keep picking random `a,b` until you get a pair for which they do exist?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Exactly. It appears mathematica is not very straightforward with procedural programming with loops.

Comment: (1) The coding is straightforward. One just needs to know the parameters of the problem. That is, are all of `a,b,u,v` sought or just, as it was worded, `u and v`? (2) Loops, should you wish to use them explicitly, can be accomplished with any of `For`, `Do`, and `While`. Same as in other languages.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Can you give a sample code with say constraints 1,2 and 4? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
primeVectors[max_, tries_] := Catch[Module[
   {a, b, done = False, tt = 0, u, v, egcd},
   While[! done && tt < tries,
    tt++;
    {a, b} = RandomInteger[{2, max}, 2];
    egcd = ExtendedGCD[a, b];
    If[egcd[[1]] =!= 1, Continue[]];
    {u, v} = {1, -1}*egcd[[2]];
    If[u < 0,
     {u, v} = {u, v} + {b, -a}; If[u < 0, Continue[]]];
    If[(! PrimeQ[a*u + b*v] || GCD[a*b, u*v] =!= 1), Continue[], 
     Throw[{{a, b}, {u, v}}]]
    ];
   $Failed
   ]]
```

examples:

```
SeedRandom[1234]
Table[primeVectors[1000, 15], 10]

(* Out[2247]= {{{899, 664}, {243, 329}}, $Failed, {{544, 
   695}, {359, -807}}, $Failed, $Failed, {{215, 
   571}, {409, -276}}, {{79, 347}, {123, 28}}, {{313, 555}, {172, 
   97}}, {{581, 155}, {151, -596}}, {{395, 313}, {42, 53}}} 7} *)
```

Comment: This is a bit complicated as I am seeing for first time. So this address 1,2 and 4?

Comment: With "PrimeQ[a*u + b*v] || GCD[a*b, u*v] =!= 1" seems address all of 1,2,3 and 4. Correct?

Comment: Yes, all four are addressed

Comment: May I ask how $a,b$ in $[T,2T]$ is guaranteed? I need a, b} = {a,b}=RandomInteger[{T,2T},2] correct?

Comment: I used `max` for your `T`. So they are selected to be less. If you want them in [T,2T] then that random generation needs to be modified slightly.